# Participating in communities

Tags: support, user-accounts

So many communities are available here in Stack Exchange. Some are related to my profession, and some are of my interests and hobbies.

Is there any restriction for joining communities? e.g. Can I only join a certain number of communities, or can I join as many communities as I want?

Comment: Question is, what makes you think there might be such limit? Explain this, and we can help you understand why it's baseless.

Comment: @ShadowWizard, I am sure that you have been here for long time but I am new here and I know that stack deals with many kinds of restrictions to keep this site's reputation good. So I do not think that I have asked a baseless question before joining the communities.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, there is no restriction of amount of communities which you join or in which you participate. Feel free to join as many communities as you want!

If you wish to later remove yourself from a community that you have joined, then this is possible too - see 
[How can I delete my account?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5999/how-can-i-delete-my-account)

Comment: And is it possible to remove myself from a community once after I joined into that?

Comment: @Code Yes, see: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5999/how-can-i-delete-my-account